# What is the proper way to save a slice of structs into Cloud Datastore (Firestore in Datastore Mode)?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I want to save a slice of structs in Google Cloud Datastore (Firestore in Datastore mode).

Take this Phonebook and Contact for example.

```
type Contact struct {
  Key         *datastore.Key `json:"id" datastore:"__key__"`
  Email       string         `json:"email" datastore:",noindex"`
  Name        string         `json:"name" datastore:",noindex"`
}
type Phonebook struct {
  Contacts []Contact
  Title    string
}
```

Saving and loading this struct is no problem as the [Datastore library](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore) takes care of it.

Due to the presence of some complex properties in my actual code, I need to implement `PropertyLoadSaver` methods.

Saving the `Title` property is straightforward. But I have problems storing the slice of Contact structs.

I tried using the `SaveStruct` method:

```
func (pb *Phonebook) Save() ([]datastore.Property, error) {
  ps := []datastore.Property{
    {
      Name:    "Title",
      Value:   pb.Title,
      NoIndex: true,
    },
  }
  ctt, err := datastore.SaveStruct(pb.Contacts)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  ps = append(ps, datastore.Property{
    Name:    "Contacts",
    Value:   ctt,
    NoIndex: true,
  })

  return ps, nil
}
```

This code compiles but doesn't work.

The error message is `datastore: invalid entity type`

Making a slice of Property explicitly also does not work:

```
func (pb *Phonebook) Save() ([]datastore.Property, error) {
  ps := []datastore.Property{
    {
      Name:    "Title",
      Value:   pb.Title,
      NoIndex: true,
    },
  }
  cttProps := datastore.Property{
    Name:    "Contacts",
    NoIndex: true,
  }
  if len(pb.Contacts) > 0 {
    props := make([]interface{}, 0, len(pb.Contacts))
    for _, contact := range pb.Contacts {
      ctt, err := datastore.SaveStruct(contact)
      if err != nil {
        return nil, err
      }
      props = append(props, ctt)
    }
    cttProps.Value = props
  }
  ps = append(ps, cttProps)

  return ps, nil
}
```

Making a slice of Entity does not work either:

```
func (pb *Phonebook) Save() ([]datastore.Property, error) {
  ps := []datastore.Property{
    {
      Name:    "Title",
      Value:   pb.Title,
      NoIndex: true,
    },
  }
  cttProps := datastore.Property{
    Name:    "Contacts",
    NoIndex: true,
  }
  if len(pb.Contacts) > 0 {
    values := make([]datastore.Entity, len(pb.Contacts))
    props := make([]interface{}, 0, len(pb.Contacts))
    for _, contact := range pb.Contacts {
      ctt, err := datastore.SaveStruct(contact)
      if err != nil {
        return nil, err
      }
      values = append(values, datastore.Entity{
        Properties: ctt,
      })
    }
    for _, v := range values {
      props = append(props, v)
    }
    cttProps.Value = props
  }
  ps = append(ps, cttProps)

  return ps, nil
}
```

Both yielded the same error `datastore: invalid entity type`

Finally I resorted to using JSON. The slice of Contact is converted into a JSON array.

```
func (pb *Phonebook) Save() ([]datastore.Property, error) {
  ps := []datastore.Property{
    {
      Name:    "Title",
      Value:   pb.Title,
      NoIndex: true,
    },
  }
  var values []byte
  if len(pb.Contacts) > 0 {
    js, err := json.Marshal(pb.Contacts)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
    values = js
  }
  ps = append(ps, datastore.Property{
    Name:    "Contacts",
    Value:   values,
    NoIndex: true,
  })

  return ps, nil
}
```

Isn't there a better way of doing this other than using JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [document](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#example-SaveStruct) and it mentions src must be a struct pointer.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Yah, it's not that. The problem here is that the property is a slice, not a struct. It is the slice that is causing all the hiccups.

Comment: can you share the part of your code where you are instantiate the datastore object  in your main function and where you call the save function ? (remember to cover you project id), I am trying to replicate this

Comment: You mean like this?

dsClient, _ := datastore.NewClient(context.Background(), datastoreName)
err := dsClient.Put(context.Background(), datastore.IncompleteKey("Phonebook", nil), &phonebook)

Comment: I found a similar issue on the api [Github] (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/216) but it was closed due to age, probably the best way to move this forward and get a solution beyond the json workaround is to report a new issue on the repo.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the direction Andres. Just wondering if you agree this should be doable? I'm guessing the authors have their reasons for not making it work. I'm not fluent enough with reflection to say what is feasible and what's not.

Comment: I think its better to create an issue on the repo and explain the situation there, and the repo contributors may address in case they consider feasible or may provide an explanation on why its not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you seem to customize the saving of PhoneBook seems to be to avoid saving the Contacts slice if there are no contacts. If so, you can just define your PhoneBook as follows and directly use SaveStruct on the PhoneBook object.

```
type Phonebook struct {
  Contacts []Contact `datastore:"Contacts,noindex,omitempty"`
  Title    string `datastore:"Title,noindex"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not it. I have other reasons for customizing the saving of Phonebook. I just omitted that part from the sample for brevity. It is not to avoid saving nil Contacts.